# Using Ultrasound for monitoring FRS in AD

Tags: active-directory

I'm looking to implement Ultrasound to monitor FRS in AD. I've a few questions around database permissions that I need answered before I deploy. I have no access to the SQL environment, therefore need to request everything up front.

- Does Ultrasound require a separate SQL instance?
- Does the database need to be pre-created or will the installation do this?
- If the installation does this, I'm assuming the account used to run the installation will require sysadmin rights on the SQL server, is this correct?
- What rights are required by the DCs to write data to the database?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultrasound doesn't require its own instance, but it might make your life easier to put it in its own MSDE instance.

The installation will create the database for you, provided you are logged-on as a user who can create a database in the selected SQL server. (This may be another good reason to use an MSDE instance.)

The controller is the only computer that access the database. It runs as "Network Service" and, if it's accessing the database on a remote computer, will do so as the AD computer account of the controller computer. (If it's accessing a local instance it will do so as SYSTEM, and thus as SA.)

The DC's don't write to the database-- the controller polls the DCs and writes to the database.

There's a lot of good information in the CHM file inside the Ultrasound setup. If you'd like to extract it without actually installing Ultrasound, download the setup and do a:

```
Setup_Ultrasound.exe /C /T:drive_and_path_to_extract_to
```

You'll find an Ultrasound.MSI in the folder you specify above. Execute the following from a command-prompt in the folder with the MSI:

```
MSIEXEC /A Ultrasound.MSI
```

You will be prompted for a path to extract into. After you've done so, nagivate to the "FRS Monitoring" subfolder of the "Program Files" subfolder of the path you've specified and you'll find the Ultrasound.CHM file.

My condolences to you for having to deal with the NTFRS. When you are able run-- don't walk-- to the DFS-R service.

Comment: +1 for DFS-R.  Upgrade your DC's to 2008 and do the DFS-R SYSVOL migration asap.  Your life will be forever changed for the better.